# how to style checkbox like a radio button in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, checkbox, webkit-appearance

I know it sounds wired. Currently I have multiple checkboxs I want to make it looks like radio button

following CSS not working in IE

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
-webkit-appearance: radio; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-appearance: radio;    /* Firefox */
appearance: radio;   //how about IE>8 ?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this link.http://help.surveygizmo.com/help/article/link/icons

Comment: I'm sure you'll find an answer for this soon enough and I'm sure you'll do it anyway, but I just want to point out that what you're asking for is to explicitly break the user experience. People are trained to see a radio button and expect it to act like a radio button. If you break that, you'll be making your site harder for people to use. Consult any UX expert and they'll tell you not to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The *appearance* property is not supported in Internet Explorer. You would need to instead target [the pseudo element `::-ms-check`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-check) and affect its presentation, and even this will only get you part-way:

```css
::-ms-check {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

As [Spudley stated in the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275630/how-to-style-checkbox-like-a-radio-button-in-ie/34277196#comment56295120_34275630), this is a bad idea. Radio buttons and checkboxes function in distinctly different ways, and users have been *taught* to distinguish between the two.