# What should I use instead '-ms-appearance: checkbox'

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, checkbox, radio-button

I have few radio buttons. I remade their appearance in that way

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7rdksuzh/)

But  `-ms-appearance: checkbox;`

it does not work on IE. 
How can I convert otherwise radiobutton on checkbox?
I do not want to draw them manually using css. I'd prefer to use something ready-made.

Comment: Have you tried the standard non-prefixed version? `appearance: checkbox;` I don't beleive Microsoft use prefixes for _any_ properties since the IE10 preview

Comment: i believe Opera and IE doesn't support appearance with or without vendor prefix (at this time 01/01/16 )

Comment: I have not tried , I checked now but does not work

Comment: IE doesn't support [appearance](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)

Comment: That I could notice. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: you could use `::-ms-check ` but checked radio button shows "dot" instead of "check mark". check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34277196/1398867). change the `border-radius` value to `4px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `-ms-appearance: checkbox;` is not working because IE and Opera browsers does not support it, even with vendor prefix.

Refer the Link:

[Browser support for appearence](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)